# Python - Two forms can't be saved separately

Tags: python, django, forms, upload

I am currently creating an upload function and I am having a hard time in saving the forms. Currently I have two separate forms, one for the profile detail and one for the upload picture only.

This is my views.py right now:

```
user = UserViewModel(username, profile)

# This method is to save the file to the directory
user.save_to_directory(userName, request.FILES['upload_picture'])

form = UserForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
     user.firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
     user.lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']

     return render(request, 'profile.html',{'message':message})
else:
     return render(request, 'profile.html',{'errorMessage':user.errorMessage})
```

This is my template:

```
<form name="upload_picture" id="upload_picture" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'actuser:profile' userName %}" method="post">
     <input type="file" name="upload_picture"/>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('upload_picture').submit();">
     Upload
</button>
<form name="update_profile" id="update_profile" action="{% url 'user:profile' userName %}" method="post">
     firstname<input type="text" name="firstname">
     lastname<input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>
```

Using this code I could save the uploaded file to the directory but the other form can't be save. There isn't really an error message when I upload the file but its asking for the other fields to be filled even though it is populated in the separate form.

What I want is to save the uploaded picture to the directory without affecting the other form, vice versa.

Thanks in advance to those who can suggest a solution.

Comment: Please show us how you are rendering the forms in the template. Also what errors do you get?

Comment: You cannot post two HTML forms at once. Your code as it is currently will only post one form - the upload_picture form. The only way to post all the data at once is to put it all inside the same form, which should work.

Comment: Is there any way that I could upload the picture without affecting the other fields? Also the same when I save the form without affecting the uploaded picture?